# Anomalous capaictor discharge in pSpice with transient analysis

Tags: pspice, orcad

I'm doing a Transient analysis of the given circuit.My question is why didn't my capacitor discharge fully,according to the graph?
[image: Circuit]

[image: Graph]

Comment: It should have decayed 63% in 10 seconds  (0.1M*100u)

Comment: it appears as if U3 has 1M leakage

Answer (score 0):

After the switch is turned off, the capacitor discharges. After it discharges, you still have current flowing through one or more of the resistors, this creates a voltage divider and the remaining voltage that you see on the node on the top of the capacitor. Look at the switches and make sure they are all 'open'. Or do a current trace on all the resistors and make sure the current is zero.